# How to generate the solutions of simple binary(Boolean) equations with multiple solutions

Tags: boolean-algebra, binary

Here's an example equation:
$$
\begin{equation}(d - x<<1)\,\& \,x =0 \,, ~0\leq2x<d 
\end{equation}
$$
where $\&$ is the logical *and* operator, $<<$ is the left bitshift operator (equivalent to multiplication by powers of 2) and $d,x$ are binary bit sequences and $d$ is known. 
It's easy enough to see that this is a system of simple Boolean equations. Denoting $d$ and $x$ as
$$
d=\begin{bmatrix}  \vdots \\ d_2 \\ d_1 \\d_0 \end{bmatrix},~~~ x=\begin{bmatrix}  \vdots \\ x_2 \\ x_1 \\x_0 \end{bmatrix} ,~~d_n,x_n \in \{0,1\}
$$
using the distributivity of $\&$ we can rewrite the equation as
$$
\begin{align} \vdots \\d_2\&x_2 &=x_1\&x_2 \\ d_1\&x_1 &=x_0\&x_1 \\ d_0\&x_0 &=0
\end{align}
$$
For instance, for $d=(10)_{10}=(1010)_2$ there are exactly 5 solutions, $x=(0)_2,(1)_2, (11)_2,(100)_2,(101)_2$. (The subscript here denotes the base)

Is there a smart way of generating the solutions to this type of system of equations? It's easy enough to iterate over the valid values of x and check each one but can we do any better? Is it at least possible to know the number of solutions?

Comment: How do you write an arithmetic subtraction as boolean *and*s? (and by the way, what's the precedence of shift here, as it's not standardized?)

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut Sorry for the confusion, I have no idea what the standard notation for this kind of thing is. The bitshift is supposed to take precedence here. As for the subtraction, I'm not aware if it's beyond the scope of pure Boolean algebra but my question is more on the side of binary arithmetic. In any case this particular problem should reduce to just logical ands assuming I didn't make a mistake writing my second equation.